# spans of spacy sentence tokenizer

Tags: python, spacy

I'm using spacy to tokenize the sentences in a document.  After tokenizing I need to be able to reconstruct the original document.  How can I get the spans of each sentence?

```
 s='this is sentence1.\nthis is sentence2.'
 nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
 doc = nlp(s)
 for sent in doc.sents:
     print(sent.text.span)

 [ 0,19]
 [19,37]
```

I want to get the span for each sentence found.  expected output for the 3 sentences would be:

Is there a way to get the span for each sent ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to get? Please provide some sample text and expected output.

Comment: I'm hoping to be able to get the span similair to how regex return both the found string and the span of the found string.  I updated the question with the expected output to achieve.

Comment: Use `print( [sent.start_char, sent.end_char] )`, it yields `[0, 19]
[19, 37]`

Comment: great - this is what I was looking for.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `sent` is of type [`spacy.tokens.span.Span`](https://spacy.io/api/span) you may access the [`start_char` and `end_char` attributes](https://spacy.io/api/span#attributes) of the object:

```
print( [sent.start_char, sent.end_char] )
```

Python test:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
s='this is sentence1.\nthis is sentence2.'
doc = nlp(s)

for sent in doc.sents:
    print( [sent.start_char, sent.end_char] )
```

Output: `[0, 19] [19, 37]`